# How to print the URL of a title field?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, uri

I'm trying to print out the url path from the title in my twig template however I haven't been successful so far.

Printing out the title containing the link works fine using:

```
{{content.title}}
```

However, I would like to seperate the URL from the title so I can use it in other areas of my twig template. For example:

```
<a href="{{ content.title.0.url }}">Example text</a>
```

I've tried various combinations and suggestions from stackexchange/drupal forums but to no avail. e.g. {{ url }}, {{ uri }} etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: What field type is your title field, is it a link field or a normal plain text field? If it’s a normal text field there's no url.

Comment: @JDrupal The title comes from the node.

Comment: I am using paragraphs with an entity reference field called "field_nodes"

Answer (score 1):

If the content that you refer to is a node then you can use the [twig path function](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#path) as follows:

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': content.id}) }}">{{ 'Example text'|t }}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Maria. It doesn't appear to be working for my case. I have added more details in the comments section above.